# Fetching json data with jQuery - named function vs. anonymous

Tags: json, jquery

The question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019950/how-to-read-json-arrays/9524431) one, but instead of using an anonymous function like the linked example, I'd prefer using a named function in order to reuse it as much as I need.

```
function parseJSON()
{
    $('#dictionary').empty();
    $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) { /*error here*/
        var html = '<div class="entry">';
        html += '<h3 class="term">' + entry['term'] + '</h3>';
        html += '<div class="part">' + entry['part'] + '</div>';
        html += '<div class="definition">';
        html += entry['definition'];
        if (entry['quote']) {
            html += '<div class="quote">';
            $.each(entry['quote'], function(lineIndex, line) {
            html += '<div class="quote-line">' + line + '</div>';
            });
            if (entry['author']) {
                html += '<div class="quote-author">' + entry['author'] + '</div>';
                }
        html += '</div>';
            }
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        $('#dictionary').append(html);
        });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
$('#letter-b a').click(function() {
$.getJSON('b.json', parseJSON());
return false;
});
});
```

This way I keep on getting a "*'data' is undefined*" error. I'm missing something trivial, I know, but I can't get it...

This is the JSON file (works perfectly with the unnamed function):

```
[
      {
        "term": "BACKBITE",
        "part": "v.t.",
        "definition": "To speak of a man as you find him when he can't find you."
      },
      {
        "term": "BEARD",
        "part": "n.",
        "definition": "The hair that is commonly cut off by those who justly execrate the absurd Chinese custom of shaving the head."
      },
      {
        "term": "BEGGAR",
        "part": "n.",
        "definition": "One who has relied on the assistance of his friends."
      },
      {
        "term": "BELLADONNA",
        "part": "n.",
        "definition": "In Italian a beautiful lady; in English a deadly poison.  A striking example of the essential identity of the two tongues."
      }
    ]
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: pass data as argument to parseJSON...also try changing your function name...I think there is already a in built function with that name

Comment: There is a parseJSON function in jQuery.  What if you rename your function to something else?

Answer (score 3):

Should be: `$.getJSON('b.json', parseJSON);`, then in the function declaration, add data as a param I think.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
$.getJSON('b.json', parseJSON());
```

You're passing in a *call* to the function `parseJSON` as the callback.

Most likely you wanted to pass the function itself, like so:

```
$.getJSON('b.json', parseJSON);
```

In the code you have now, `parseJSON()` is first called and its result is passed in as callback.

Also, you'll need to make sure the signature of the callback function complies with what jQuery expects - see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
So in your `parseJSON` function, you would probably need to add `data` as an argument, like so:

```
function parseJSON(data) {
   ...your code here...
}
```

(Note that it doesn't always have to be wrong to use a function call as callback. In case your function passes the actual callback function back as return value, then you could have a call there. For example:

```
function getParseCallBack() {
    return parseJSON;
}
```

Then you could do:

```
$.getJSON('b.json', getParseCallBack());
```

I'm not suggesting that you use this at this point - I'm just trying to clarify the difference between a function and a call to a function.)